# SQL Server - Insertar bloque de registros a una tabla con datos de otras tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos días, espero me puedan ayudar ya que recién estoy empezando a aplicar en lo que es SQL Server, estoy trabajando en un sistema de planilla de trabajadores y quería saber la forma de como insertar en una tabla (Planilla.dbf) algunos datos de la tabla (trabajador.dbf) mas algun otro campo de otra tabla, ojito que son tablas con campos diferentes, 
[image: Boceto de las tablas]

Bueno tal como se ve en la imagen mi idea es que al insertar un mes se registre automáticamente en la tabla planilla.dbf con los datos de la tabla trabajadores, con el campo del mes(id_planilla) y el porcentaje que depende del campo sueldo.

No se si hacerlo con un procedimiento almacenado que contenga un Trigger o algún cursor o con la combinación de ambos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hacerlo sería sencillo con unos subselects, pero te pregunto, cuando asignas el MES, en la plantilla, como sabes que trabajadores estaban dentro de ese mes? y otra pregunta en todos los meses cobran el mismo sueldo??

Comment: Bueno la tabla trabajador tiene otros campos en donde unos de ellos es condicion(habilitado o deshabilitado según sea el caso), el sueldo siempre es el mismo lo que varian son algunas comisiones o porcentajes que dependen del suelto entre otras cosas.

Comment: Eso significa que por cada mes que tienes debes registrar los mismos empleados con el porcentaje que les toque, es así?

Comment: Los empleados ya están registrado en la tabla trabajador, lo que deseo es que se trasladen a la tabla planilla solo algunos campos mas otros campos de otra tabla para que en la tabla planilla estén registrado todos los datos de una planilla, ID-planilla, trabajador, sueldo, descuentos, aportes, entre otros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, basandome en tu ejemplo, la sentencia debe ser así:

```
INSERT INTO Planilla 
VALUES (id_plantilla, id_trabajador, porcentaje)
SELECT Mes.id_mes, 
    Trabajador.id_trabajador, 
    Trabajador.formula_porcentaje  --  Esta columna es solo un ejemplo para el calculo de tu porcentaje.
FROM Mes, Trabajador
WHERE Mes.id_mes = '01'  --  En caso de que tengas una condición.
```

Con ello puedes generar un insert en una tabla desde multiples tablas. Basta con definir las columnas que obtendran valores en **VALUES** y que en el **SELECT** coincidan los mismo, por tipos de datos y longitud. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda su aporte.